# Android Application wallpaper functionality not implemented; not sure why?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, wallpapermanager

I am trying to follow a few different tutorials to have a `ViewPager` that lets a user swipe through images and then set the currently viewed image as their wallpaper. so far I have not been successful in getting the wallpaper set, and there is an issue with performance as the user swipes through the photos, performance degrades dramatically.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
ViewPager mViewPager;
int[] mImages = {R.drawable.example__1_, R.drawable.example__2_, R.drawable.example__3_,
        R.drawable.example__4_, R.drawable.example__5_, R.drawable.example__6_,
        R.drawable.example__7_, R.drawable.example__8_, R.drawable.example__9_,
        R.drawable.example__10_, R.drawable.example__11_, R.drawable.example__12_};
item mViewPagerAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewPagerMain);
    mViewPagerAdapter = new item(MainActivity.this, mImages);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mViewPagerAdapter);
    final int set = mViewPager.getCurrentItem();

    Button button = findViewById(R.id.SetWall);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                    "Setting Wallpaper... 1/2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            WallpaperManager wpm
                    = WallpaperManager.getInstance(getApplicationContext());
            try {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Setting Wallpaper... 2/2", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                wpm.setResource(set);
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Wallpaper Set!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            catch (IOException e) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Have you set the permission in your Manifest.xml file like this?

   ```
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SET_WALLPAPER" />
   ```
2. This is because your pages get destroyed and recreated every time they get off screen which happens when you swipe to the next.

   To make ViewPager smoother use `mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(NumberOfPages-1);`
   after you set the adapter (`mViewPager.setAdapter();`)

Comment: Thank you, the ViewPager is a lot smoother now thanks!

Comment: But I already had the uses-permission line added to my manifest and the problem persists, i.e. it does not actually set the wallpaper? any other ideas would be greatly appricated.

Comment: Instead of `wpm.setResource(set);` try `wpm.setResource(this.mImages[set]);`. `mViewPager.getCurrentItem();` returns an index and `wpm.setResource()` takes a bitmap as parameter.